# Can checkboxes simply be replaced by comboboxes with virtually the same code? Or are there extra processes to be considered?

Tags: excel, vba

I have written code in VBA that takes uses checkboxes to perform some simple copy and pasting tasks based on a checkbox selection, i.e. if checkbox1 = true then do this, elseif checkbox2 = true then do some other thing. What I really want to do is improve the user experience with some comboboxes. I have tried replacing the checkboxes with comboboxes with, by validating the strings and using if/else statements. However, it does not run as expected.

CASE1: using checkboxes

```
Sub ShowUserForm()

Data_UF.Show

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim filename As String
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Otherfile.xlsm"
    
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range


    
    If Choice1.Value = True Then
        
        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:B7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")
    
        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        wk.Close saveChanges:=False
        
    ElseIf Choice2.Value = True Then

        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Source").Range("E1:F7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")

        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wk.Close saveChanges:=False
    
    End If

End Sub
```

VS.

CASE2: using comboboxes

```
Sub ShowUserForm()

Data_UF.Show

End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

    Dim filename As String
    filename = ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "Otherfile.xlsm"
    
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Set wk = Workbooks.Open(filename, ReadOnly:=True)
    
    Dim rgSource As Range, rgDestination As Range


    
    If ComboBox1.Value = "Somestring in combo box" Then
        
        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Source").Range("A1:B7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")
    
        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
    
        wk.Close saveChanges:=False
        
    ElseIf ComboBox1.Value = "Somestring other in combo box" Then

        ' set rgsource = [workbook].[worksheet].[range]
        Set rgSource = wk.Worksheets("Source").Range("E1:F7")
        Set rgDestination = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Destination").Range("A1")

        rgSource.Copy
        rgDestination.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wk.Close saveChanges:=False
    
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Comboboxes should be used when only one item can be selected at a time. Checkboxes are used when zero or more items can be selected (none checked, one checked, two checked, etc.). Use whichever is appropriate for your situation.

Comment: For this application, the purpose is for only one item to be selected at a time. How do I make that work?

Comment: By putting all of the items in one combobox. The user can only select a single item, which you can then use to branch your logic. You can improve it by not using the text and using the item's index instead, which will be much cleaner and perform better - numeric comparisons are faster than string comparisons.

Comment: Thank you, I will try the indexing. But why is it that code doesn't work for strings? Is my logic incorrect? And the different strings have always been in one combobox i.e. combobox1

Comment: I don't know what *that code doesn't work for strings* means, or *it doesn't run as expected* either. String comparisons are difficult to use - a simple typo or an extra or missing space or a case difference ("one" vs. "One" vs "onE" are all different) can cause it to fail. You've not described a specific problem yet. I addressed in my first comment what you asked in your question title, which is the only question you've asked so far. Also, what happens when you step through the code in the debugger?

Comment: Apologies. I mean doesn't work as in, it wasn't copying and pasting the values for CASE 2, as it was in CASE 1. Also it works now after switching from a mac to a windows. Very weird... Do you have references for indexing that you can recommend to improve my code, but also improve my VBA skills. I've just started VBA yesterday, so I am fairly new. Thank you Ken!